# jquery sliders that change background of other sliders

Tags: html, jquery, css

I have 4 sliders/range to change colors

1st slider. cool white to warm white
2nd slider. range of colors
3rd slider. set by 1st slider to set by 2nd slider
4rd slider. black to set by 3rd slider.

So far I can use 1st slider and 2nd slider to set the background color of the 3rd slider. The issue I'm having trouble with, I think, is in the Javascript to change the gradient to pick the color, but for all I know I'm going the wrong way. I'm not sure where I downloaded them from but I'm using jquery-1.12.4.

```js
let root = document.documentElement;
var bodyStyles = window.getComputedStyle(document.body);

$("#white").slider({
  min: 1,
  slide: function(event, ui) {
    var colorRange = []
    $.each(whitegradient, function(index, value) {
      if (ui.value <= value[0]) {
        colorRange = [index - 1, index]
        return false;
      }
    });

    //Get the two closest colors
    var firstcolor = whitegradient[colorRange[0]][1];
    var secondcolor = whitegradient[colorRange[1]][1];

    //Calculate ratio between the two closest colors
    var firstcolor_x = (whitegradient[colorRange[0]][0] / 100);
    var secondcolor_x = (whitegradient[colorRange[1]][0] / 100) - firstcolor_x;
    var slider_x = (ui.value / 100) - firstcolor_x;
    var ratio = slider_x / secondcolor_x

    //Get the color with pickHex(thx, less.js's mix function!)
    result = pickHex(secondcolor, firstcolor, ratio);
    result1 = pickHexRed(secondcolor, firstcolor, ratio);
    result2 = pickHexGreen(secondcolor, firstcolor, ratio);
    result3 = pickHexBlue(secondcolor, firstcolor, ratio);
    //        alert(result1 + ',' + result2 + ',' + result3);
    root.style.setProperty('--resultsliderwhite', result.join());
    root.style.setProperty('--resultsliderwhitered', result1.join());
    root.style.setProperty('--resultsliderwhitegreen', result2.join());
    root.style.setProperty('--resultsliderwhiteblue', result3.join());
  }
});

$("#color").slider({
  min: 1,
  slide: function(event, ui) {
    var colorRange = []
    $.each(colorgradient, function(index, value) {
      if (ui.value <= value[0]) {
        colorRange = [index - 1, index]
        return false;
      }
    });

    //Get the two closest colors
    var firstcolor = colorgradient[colorRange[0]][1];
    var secondcolor = colorgradient[colorRange[1]][1];

    //Calculate ratio between the two closest colors
    var firstcolor_x = (colorgradient[colorRange[0]][0] / 100);
    var secondcolor_x = (colorgradient[colorRange[1]][0] / 100) - firstcolor_x;
    var slider_x = (ui.value / 100) - firstcolor_x;
    var ratio = slider_x / secondcolor_x

    //Get the color with pickHex(thx, less.js's mix function!)
    result = pickHex(secondcolor, firstcolor, ratio);
    result1 = pickHexRed(secondcolor, firstcolor, ratio);
    result2 = pickHexGreen(secondcolor, firstcolor, ratio);
    result3 = pickHexBlue(secondcolor, firstcolor, ratio);
    //        alert(result1 + ',' + result2 + ',' + result3);
    root.style.setProperty('--resultslidercolorred', result1);
    root.style.setProperty('--resultslidercolorgreen', result2);
    root.style.setProperty('--resultslidercolorblue', result3);
    root.style.setProperty('--resultslidercolor', result.join());

  }
});

$("#white2color").slider({
  min: 1,
  slide: function(event, ui) {
    var colorRange = []
    $.each(white2colorgradient, function(index, value) {
      if (ui.value <= value[0]) {
        colorRange = [index - 1, index]
        return false;
      }
    });

    //Get the two closest colors
    var firstcolor = white2colorgradient[colorRange[0]][1];
    var secondcolor = white2colorgradient[colorRange[1]][1];

    //Calculate ratio between the two closest colors
    var firstcolor_x = (white2colorgradient[colorRange[0]][0] / 100);
    var secondcolor_x = (white2colorgradient[colorRange[1]][0] / 100) - firstcolor_x;
    var slider_x = (ui.value / 100) - firstcolor_x;
    var ratio = slider_x / secondcolor_x

    //Get the color with pickHex(thx, less.js's mix function!)
    result = pickHex(secondcolor, firstcolor, ratio);
    result1 = pickHexRed(secondcolor, firstcolor, ratio);
    result2 = pickHexGreen(secondcolor, firstcolor, ratio);
    result3 = pickHexBlue(secondcolor, firstcolor, ratio);
    //        alert(result1 + ',' + result2 + ',' + result3);
    root.style.setProperty('--resultsliderw2cred', result1);
    root.style.setProperty('--resultsliderw2cgreen', result2);
    root.style.setProperty('--resultsliderw2cblue', result3);
    root.style.setProperty('--resultsliderw2c', result.join());
  }
});

$("#sliderbrightness").slider({
  min: 1,
  slide: function(event, ui) {
    var colorRange = []
    $.each(brightnessgradient, function(index, value) {
      if (ui.value <= value[0]) {
        colorRange = [index - 1, index]
        return false;
      }
    });

    //Get the two closest colors
    var firstcolor = brightnessgradient[colorRange[0]][1];
    var secondcolor = brightnessgradient[colorRange[1]][1];

    //Calculate ratio between the two closest colors
    var firstcolor_x = (brightnessgradient[colorRange[0]][0] / 100);
    var secondcolor_x = (brightnessgradient[colorRange[1]][0] / 100) - firstcolor_x;
    var slider_x = (ui.value / 100) - firstcolor_x;
    var ratio = slider_x / secondcolor_x

    //Get the color with pickHex(thx, less.js's mix function!)
    result1 = pickHexRed(secondcolor, firstcolor, ratio);
    result2 = pickHexGreen(secondcolor, firstcolor, ratio);
    result3 = pickHexBlue(secondcolor, firstcolor, ratio);
    //        alert(result1 + ',' + result2 + ',' + result3);
    root.style.setProperty('--resultsliderbrightnessred', result1);
    root.style.setProperty('--resultsliderbrightnessgreen', result2);
    root.style.setProperty('--resultsliderbrightnessblue', result3);
  }
});

function pickHex(color1, color2, weight) {
  var p = weight;
  var w = p * 2 - 1;
  var w1 = (w / 1 + 1) / 2;
  var w2 = 1 - w1;
  var rgb = [Math.round(color1[0] * w1 + color2[0] * w2),
    Math.round(color1[1] * w1 + color2[1] * w2),
    Math.round(color1[2] * w1 + color2[2] * w2)
  ];
  return rgb;
}

function pickHexRed(color1, color2, weight) {
  var p = weight;
  var w = p * 2 - 1;
  var w1 = (w / 1 + 1) / 2;
  var w2 = 1 - w1;
  var rgb = [Math.round(color1[0] * w1 + color2[0] * w2)];
  return rgb;
}

function pickHexGreen(color1, color2, weight) {
  var p = weight;
  var w = p * 2 - 1;
  var w1 = (w / 1 + 1) / 2;
  var w2 = 1 - w1;
  var rgb = [Math.round(color1[1] * w1 + color2[1] * w2)];
  return rgb;
}

function pickHexBlue(color1, color2, weight) {
  var p = weight;
  var w = p * 2 - 1;
  var w1 = (w / 1 + 1) / 2;
  var w2 = 1 - w1;
  var rgb = [Math.round(color1[2] * w1 + color2[2] * w2)];
  return rgb;
}

var slidercolorred = bodyStyles.getPropertyValue('--resultslidercolorred');
var slidercolorgreen = bodyStyles.getPropertyValue('--resultslidercolorgreen');
var slidercolorblue = bodyStyles.getPropertyValue('--resultslidercolorblue');
var sliderwhitered = bodyStyles.getPropertyValue('--resultsliderwhitered');
var sliderwhitegreen = bodyStyles.getPropertyValue('--resultsliderwhitegreen');
var sliderwhiteblue = bodyStyles.getPropertyValue('--resultsliderwhiteblue');

var whitegradient = [
  [0, [210, 223, 255]],
  [100, [255, 159, 70]],
];

var colorgradient = [
  [0, [255, 0, 0]],
  [33, [0, 255, 0]],
  [66, [0, 0, 255]],
  [100, [255, 0, 0]],
];

var white2colorgradient = [
  [0, [sliderwhitered, sliderwhitegreen, sliderwhiteblue]],
  [100, [slidercolorred, slidercolorgreen, slidercolorblue]],
];

var brightnessgradient = [
  [0, [0, 0, 0]],
  [100, [255, 0, 0]],
];
```

```css
.slidercolor {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 12px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, hsl(0, 100%, 50%), hsl(10, 100%, 50%), hsl(20, 100%, 50%), hsl(30, 100%, 50%), hsl(40, 100%, 50%), hsl(50, 100%, 50%), hsl(60, 100%, 50%), hsl(70, 100%, 50%), hsl(80, 100%, 50%), hsl(90, 100%, 50%), hsl(100, 100%, 50%), hsl(110, 100%, 50%), hsl(120, 100%, 50%), hsl(130, 100%, 50%), hsl(140, 100%, 50%), hsl(150, 100%, 50%), hsl(160, 100%, 50%), hsl(170, 100%, 50%), hsl(180, 100%, 50%), hsl(190, 100%, 50%), hsl(200, 100%, 50%), hsl(210, 100%, 50%), hsl(220, 100%, 50%), hsl(230, 100%, 50%), hsl(240, 100%, 50%), hsl(250, 100%, 50%), hsl(260, 100%, 50%), hsl(270, 100%, 50%), hsl(280, 100%, 50%), hsl(290, 100%, 50%), hsl(300, 100%, 50%), hsl(310, 100%, 50%), hsl(320, 100%, 50%), hsl(330, 100%, 50%), hsl(340, 100%, 50%), hsl(350, 100%, 50%), hsl(360, 100%, 50%));
  outline: none;
}

.sliderwhite2color {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 12px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(left, rgb(var(--resultsliderwhite)), rgb(var(--resultslidercolor)));
  outline: none;
}

.sliderbrightness {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 12px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(left, black, rgb(var(--resultsliderw2c)));
  outline: none;
}

.sliderwhite {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 12px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(left, rgb(220, 226, 243), rgb(255, 159, 70));
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
White
<div id="white" min="0" max="360" step="1" class="sliderwhite"></div>
Color
<div id="color" min="0" max="360" step="1" class="slidercolor"></div>
White to Color
<div id="white2color" min="0" max="100" step="1" class="sliderwhite2color"></div>
Brightness
<div id="brightness" min="0" max="100" step="1" class="sliderbrightness"></div>
```

Comment: Which slider library are you using? jQueryUI?

Comment: sorry. yes im using jquery-ui.js from 1.12.4